# Почему возвращает пустое значение и не создает csv-файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def main():
    pattern = 'https://forum.dirt.ru/member.php?u={}'

    for i in range(0, 76128):
        url = pattern.format(str(i))
        get_html(url)

def get_html(url):
    rs = requests.get(url)
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    nickname = root.select_one('.bigusername').text.strip()
    data = {
            'nickname': nickname}
    write_csv(data)

def write_csv(data):
    with open('nickname.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((data['nickname']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Почему возвращает пустое значение и не создает csv-файл?

Comment: main вызываете? у вас в `def get_html():` ошибка -- нет параметра `url`. Это тот, код что вы используете или при составлении вопроса опечатались?

Comment: Тот что использую. Добавил url в get_html - все равно пустое значение возвращает.

Comment: Хм, непонятно что у вас творится. Видите в чем дело, в вопросе один код, у вас другой. И проблема у вас и с тем, и с другим. Поместите в вопрос ваш код (кнопка `править`) Проверяли что в `data` находится?

Comment: Добавьте в конце: `if __name__ == '__main__':` `main()`, а то у вас код не выполняется

Comment: Ошибка. 
 File "/home/qwerty0571/Desktop/ishod.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/qwerty0571/Desktop/ishod.py", line 10, in main
    get_html(url)
  File "/home/qwerty0571/Desktop/ishod.py", line 15, in get_html
    nickname = root.select_one('.bigusername').text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Изменил код в вопросе.

Comment: Воот! Текущая ошибка из-за того что `root.select_one('.bigusername').` вернул None, т.е. тот никнейм не был найден при загрузке. Вангую что вы своим циклом устроили дос-атаку на сайт и тот при какой-то итерации вернул заглушку, например с капчей

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста почему при удалении из строки 
nickname = root.select_one('.bigusername').text.strip() метода strip программа выдает ошибку 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qwerty0571/Desktop/ishod.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/qwerty0571/Desktop/ishod.py", line 10, in main
    get_html(pattern)
  File "/home/qwerty0571/Desktop/ishod.py", line 15, in get_html
    nickname = root.select_one('.bigusername').text()
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Comment: Со strip на выходе в csv файле имеем ник, записанный по буквам в разные столбцы одной строки. Почему так? Ведь strip просто удаляет лишние символы в конце и в начале.

Comment: потому что не нужно для `.text` писать скобки -- это не функция

Comment: А почему вы решили что это strip такое возвращает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного модифицировал код и поставил ограничение на цикл:

```
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def write_csv(data):
    with open('nickname.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        # Список на 1 элемент
        row = [data['nickname']]
        writer.writerow(row)


def get_html(url):
    rs = requests.get(url)
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    nickname = root.select_one('.bigusername').text.strip()
    data = {'nickname': nickname}
    write_csv(data)


def main():
    pattern = 'https://forum.dirt.ru/member.php?u={}'

    for i in range(3):
        url = pattern.format(i + 1)
        get_html(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Результат (nickname.csv):

```
Dronix
testing_vbulletin
kolyanich
```